# Xcode 10 Git how to update .gitignore to ignore new project files related to cocoapods?

Tags: git, cocoapods, gitignore, xcode10

I have a `.gitignore` set up to ignore cocoa pod related files. However, I've done a new **pod install** for an Xcode 10 project to fix an unrelated issue and see that there's a number of new pod-related files added to source control. Is this related to using Xcode 10?

**How do I update my .gitignore file to ignore new file/folder types (if any) added with Xcode 10 project format?**

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you use glob expressions in your gitignore to exclude all files that match certain pattern? Something along the lines `Exam3Alex/Pods/Target Support Files/*`?

Comment: I want to have a universal pattern which may be shared between projects, if there's some new file storage structure in XCode 10 :(

Comment: Adding new entries in `.gitignore` that are "XCode 10 specific" shouldn't break anything when the same gitignore is used elsewhere.

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek any updates?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing in Xcode 10 that wasn't already in Xcode 9.3 and Xcode 9.4. So a contemporary multi-project `.gitignore` file may nowadays simply be:

```
# Ignore macOS Finder user-related files
.DS_Store

# Ignore Xcode user-related files
xcuserdata/

# Ignore AppCode user-related files
.idea/

# Ignore CocoaPods installed files
Pods/

# Ignore Carthage installed files
Carthage/
```

Use the `!` syntax if you do **not** want to ignore a file:

```
# I want to keep that file for some reason (not recommended)
!Pods/Pods.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Some popular reference `.gitignore` but slowly getting old (disclaimer: I've committed on those):

- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/Xcode.gitignore
- https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Objective-C.gitignore